# Edit Website with Emacs

Tags: html, emacs

If you have a remote web host, say 000webhost or Godaddy, is there a way you can edit the site with emacs without editing via the website. Please note that I don't *have* to use emacs, I'd just prefer it.

Comment: I use git with Emacs. I had to identify the OS used by the shared host; then I located that DVD for the OS and created a virtual OS on my home computer (or you could partition and have a dedicated disk); then I built git on that virtual OS; then I uploaded that git to my shared host; then the rest is history -- i.e., I push from my home machine to the server using git and this method has the benefit of version control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Tramp Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode), you could use [Ange Ftp](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AngeFtp) and you could use [Kio](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Kio), and there are almost certainly an absurd number of other (e.g. [VFS](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/vfs/vfs.html)) approaches that would work.